# how to stop & start mp4 in Powerpoint c# vsto

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

I am able to add MP4 video on PowerPoint slide , and I want to play programmatically and once it finished playing its need to move next slide automatically and another video start in next slide .

```
  var shape = objSlides.Shapes.AddMediaObject2(@"C:\\Users\\Rajan\\Downloads\\sample-5s.mp4", MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse, 10, 10);
```

Anyone please help me to suggest any property name which provide running or stop status of mp4 on current  slide  .

Answer (score 0):

The PowerPoint object model does not provide any COM methods to play and stop an embedded video. You can try using Windows API functions or [Microsoft Active Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) to simulate clicks to start the video, but that is not a trivial task.

For example, in VBA you could use the `SendKeys` method:

```
Sub Test()
  Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Select
  SendKeys "%p", True
End Sub
```